# Rewriting git history to unpack a squashed commit

Tags: git, github, version-control

I currently have a branch `develop` that contains a squashed merge commit of about 30 commits from another branch, `develop-2`. This squashed commit is not at `HEAD`, it is maybe 20-30 or so commits prior to `HEAD`. I still have the `develop-2` branch around with all of the individual commits that it constituted of.

How would one perform Git surgery on this repository to "unpack" the squashed commit and replace it in Git history with its individual commits from the `develop-2` branch?

Comment: `git reflog` is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would checkout commit before the squashed commit, create a branch and merge your unsquashed commits.

Then `git cherry-pick` the range of commits from your old history on top of this new branch.

Something like the following.

```
B' = squashed b2
        A     B'    C    D
dev - - * - - * - - * -- *
dev2    \ - - * - - * - - *
               b1    b2    b3

Step 1 & 2: `git checkout <sha-A> && git checkout -b d3  && git merge dev2`
        A     B'    C    D
dev - - * - - * - - * -- *
d3  - - * - - b1 - - b2 - - b3

Step 3: `git cherry-pick <sha B'>..dev`
d3  - - A - - b1 - - b2 - - b3 - - C - - D
```

The above steps are non-destructive to your current branches.

Comment: If this works as desired, do a `git checkout dev && git reset --hard d3` so move the dev branch to d3 HEAD. Beware when doing this if its code that has been pushed somewhere. You'll need to do a `git push --force` to get it up there and that will cause issues for others.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be too hard using 'git rebase --onto'

Answer (score 0):

Assume your branch structure as below graph (C’ is the squash merge from `develop-2`):

```
A---C0---B---C’---D---...---X  develop
     \         
      C1---C2---...---C30      develop-2
```

You can use these steps unpack `C’` on `develop` branch:

**1.`git rebase --onto <commit id for B> <commit id for C0> <commit id for C30>`**

```
           C1’---C2’---...---C30’  HEAD
          /
A---C0---B---C’---D---...---X      develop
     \         
      C1---C2---...---C30          develop-2
```

**2.`git rebase --onto <commit id now HEAD is> <commit id for C’> develop`**

```
A---C0---B---C1’---C2’---...---C30’---D---...---X  develop
     \         
      C1---C2---...---C30                          develop-2
```